# Is there better way to write class of pathutils more concise elegant way?

Tags: dart

I've developed a Dart program for path manipulation and utilities involving directories and files. While the code functions correctly, I'm seeking feedback on its elegance and whether there might be more efficient or elegant approaches. I lack full confidence in the current implementation, so I'm reaching out to the Stack Overflow community, known for its wealth of expertise, for valuable insights. Thank you in advance for any feedback and suggestions

````
   class PathUtils {

      String slash = Platform.pathSeparator;

      String Join(List<String> path) {

           String filePath = "";

           for (var p in path) {
  
               p += this.slash;

               filePath += p;
           }

        return filePath.substring(0, filePath.length - 1);
      }

    String BaseName(String fullPath) {
   
    String pathSeparator = Platform.pathSeparator;

    if (fullPath.contains("/")) {

      pathSeparator = '/';

    }
    return fullPath.split(pathSeparator).last;
  }

  bool isDir(String fullPath) {
    return Directory(fullPath).statSync().type == FileSystemEntityType.file;
  }

  String Extension(String fullPath) {

    bool pathType = isDir(fullPath);

    String file = fullPath;

    if (pathType == true) {

      file = file.split(".").last;

    } else {

      file = "is a folder";

    }
    return file;
  }
}```


The code works as expected but I want someone to rephrase my code in better way than I if it is good as it is then I am happy thank you.
```
````

Comment: `Join` could be just `path.join(slash)`. `Extension`'s return value is quite ambiguous.  What if a file is named `foo.is a folder`?  Do you really want it to return the same thing for files named `foo` and `.foo`?  I would strongly suggest following the semantics of established APIs (e.g. Python's [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)).  Or better yet, just use [`package:path`](https://pub.dev/packages/path).

Comment: You may get better answers on the Code Review Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend using `package:path`, and not try to do everything yourself.

To fit with Dart style and traditions, this is how I *would* write what you have:

```dart
/// A utility object for manipulating file system paths.
class PathUtils {
  /// The configured path separator.
  ///
  /// For compatibility with the current operating system,
  /// use the default [Platform.pathSeparator], which is 
  /// always one of `r"\"` or `"/"`.
  final String pathSeparator;

  /// Creates a `PathUtils` using the given [pathSeparator].
  ///
  /// Defaults to [Platform.pathSeparator] if [pathSeparator] is omitted.
  PathUtils({String? pathSeparator}) 
      : pathSeparator = pathSeparator ?? Platform.pathSeparator;

  /// The path segments, as an absolute path.
  ///
  /// Starts with a path separator, does not end with one
  /// unles [pathSegments] constains no path segments.
  String join(Iterable<String> pathSegments) {
    Buffer buffer = StringBuffer();
    for (var pathSegment in pathSegments) {
      buffer..write(pathSeparator)..write(pathSegment);
    }
    if (buffer.isEmpty) return pathSeparator;
    return buffer.toString();
  }

  /// The last path segment of the [fullPath].
  ///
  /// Everything after the last [pathSeparator], or the entire [fullPath]
  /// if it contains no path separators.
  ///
  /// Is empty if [fullPath] ends in a path separator, or is empty.
  String baseName(String fullPath) {
    var lastSeparatorIndex = fullPath.lastIndexOf(pathSeparator);
    return fullPath.substring(lastSeparatorIndex + 1);
  }

  /// Whether [fullPath] is the path of a directory.
  bool isDir(String fullPath) => Directory(fullPath).existsSync();

  /// The part of the [baseName] after the last `.` character.
  ///
  /// Is empty if the [baseName] ends in `.`,
  /// or if it contains nothing but `.` characters before the last `.`.
  /// In that case, the part after the `.` is considered part of the proper
  /// name. This includes base names like `.config` or `..`.
  String extension(String fullPath) {
    for (var i = fullPath.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (fullPath.startsWith(".", i)) {
        // Found `.` before path separator.
        // Check that there is something before that `.` in the path segment.
        for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
          if (fullPath.startsWith(pathSeparator, j)) {
            return ""; // No non `.`-chars before `.` in basename.
          }
          if (!fullPath.startsWith(".", j)) {
            return fullPath.substring(i + 1);
          }
        }
        break;
      }
      if (fullPath.startsWith(pathSeparator, i)) break;
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```